# How to read text file and reformat in only two columns in Java?

Tags: java, file, text, java.util.scanner

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
House1 25456 22456 54564 54564
House2 54788 54756
```

House(it could be up t 1500 houses)

and I want it to look like this:

```
House1 25456 
House1 22456 
House1 54564 
House1 54564
House2 54788
House2 54756

House(again same principle)
```

code

```
public class Houses {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UsingScanner();
    }
    public static void UsingScanner(){
        try{
            Scanner sc = new Scanner (new File("C:\\Test.txt"));
            while (sc.hasNextLine()){
                System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Ups! you got a problem");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use camelCase for method names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use String.split() to extract the house numbers. Then loop through them to print it (or collect it to a StringBuilder if needed). eg:

```
           while (sc.hasNextLine()){
                String[] tokens = sc.nextLine().split("\\s+");
                String houseName = tokens[0];
                for(int i=1; i< tokens.length ; i++)
                    System.out.println(houseName + " " + tokens[i]);
            }
```

Comment: I used your code as follows and It worked just fine. However I noticed that the we could have a condition when House(Number) might not have any codes beside it. for example, house2 does not have any codes:

House1 25456 
House2 
House3 87888 88889 87724

I think I will have to add an if condition before printing them out.

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] parts = sc.nextLine().split();
for (int i=1;i<parts.length;i++){
    out.write(parts[0]+" "+parts[i]);
}
```

Assuming `out` is an OutputStream.

Comment: Thank  you for your comments!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to keep it as simpler as possible and with less possible changes with respect to your original code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Houses {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UsingScanner();
    }

    public static void UsingScanner() {
        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Test.txt"));
            //fw is to write you desired result into the Output.txt file
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File("C:\\Output.txt"));
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                //split your line by spaces into an array of Strings
                String[] splitted = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
                //at index zero of the array there is always the house name
                for (int k = 1; k < splitted.length; k++) { //so start the loop from index 1
                    //loop every numeric item of a line, write the house name and the numeric item
                    fw.write(splitted[0] + " " + splitted[k] + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                }
                //step to the next house name (another line)
            }
            fw.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Ups! you got a problem");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Than you for sharing! The end goal is to save it into a new document just like you suggested. I already have to code for the output. For simplicity, only put is in system.out.println():

Comment: I tried the File writer above, and it is not saving the data in splitted[0] space splitted[k] and return a new line. What it is doing, it is printing everything in one line.

Comment: @joshua this is probably because you are using Windows, and the character '\n' (which I appended at the end of every loop in the previous answer version) is not enough to render actually a new line.
Now I modified my answer by replacing '\n' whith System.getProperty("line.separator") (it return the platform dependent line separator) and it should work.